# How can I get .less compiler support in Visual Studio 2012 Release 2?

Tags: css, visual-studio, less

I read that now in VS2012 there is .less compiler support. I mean support for the Less compiler that compiles into CSS.

However when I open a .less file it still only gives me the single less pane and does not seem to compile.

How can I enable .less support.

What about VS2012 Release 3  or VS2013 support. Is there better support for .less in either of those?

Comment: do you have the web essentials installed?

Comment: No because I was reading that they now added some of the web essentials features into release 2 and removed them from web essentials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual studio doesn't have an auto-compilation feature for less files. It only provides syntax-highlighting for .less files.

You can compile your LESS files using a plugin like [Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench/getting-started) or [Web Essentials 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6)

Comment: Thanks - I'm confused however because Web Essentials did this with version: 2.5 - February 17, 2013
•Removed LESS/CoffeeScript editors

Comment: np, yes I got it, Maybe they remove because Visual studio 12 update 2 have native LESS support. I simply prefer SimpLESS or Winless for automatically less compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a Visual Studio extension, but I recommend WinLess (http://winless.org/) as a solution for compiling Less files for Windows users.

You may have it running and tracking your Less files, and it will automatically compile them when saved.

It worked for me compiling some files that use modern Less features, while SimpLess (http://wearekiss.com/simpless) failed to compile them.